# What are these flat surfaces on a worm gear's teeth for?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

Does this affect the gear's performance?
[image: Source: McMaster-Carr]

Comment: that part does not need to be machined, so it is left untouched ... think about this `what would be the tooth shape if the gear was double the width`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Images generated by manipulating an [OnShape public assembly](https://cad.onshape.com/documents/9a7ee1bbe89c5ffc5b67073b/w/1463c9bcf07360d5cf71a0ea/e/3b660bcdfeadf47211ce9535?renderMode=0&uiState=64b1a54eb854d43a639b60a3).

It should be clear from the third image that the shap of the gear is designed to maximise contact are and to provide relief for the shaft of the worm. The tops of the teeth indicated in your image are flattened to prevent interference with the worm shaft.

Comment: That's clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

the curve in the tooth is to clear the minor diameter of the worm gear so the worm and the tooth can engage fully.